# Forecasting and lapply function

Tags: r, loops, lapply, forecast

I am foresting with combination of data sets from expsmooth package and forecasting function from the forecast package.

```
#Example 1
    require("forecast")
    require("expsmooth") # required for the data

    # Fit an ETS model to the first 45 months - Training set
    Training_set_model <- ets(usnetelec[1:45])

    # Apply the same model to the last 10 months without re-estimating the parameters- Test set
    Test_set_model <- ets(usnetelec[46:55],model=Training_set_model)  #<--------------------------------
```

In order to get more accurate projection I divide data set into Training set and Test set. Main idea here is to make automated selection of models with Training set and apply this model with Test set.
So far so good :)
But problem occurs when I want to apply this code in matrix with several times series.For example I use code below:

```
#Example 2
    library(fpp2)
    library(forecast)

    Data_Set<-uschange[,1:4]

    # Training set
    Training_set = window(Data_Set, start=1970, end=c(2010,4))

    # Test set
    Test_set = window(Data_Set, start=2011, end=c(2016,3))

    # Forecasting with Training set
    Forecast_Training_set<-lapply(Training_set, ets)
```

Тhe upper code works fine. But the problem is with the above line of code which needs to make forecast with Test Set like Example 1.

```
   # Forecasting with Test set
    Forecast_Test_set<- lapply(Test_set, ets(model=Forecast_Training_set)) #<-----------------------
```

So can anybody help me how to fix this line of code in order to get forecast like prevous example ( line of code with Test_set_model Example 1).

Comment: You can try `Forecast_Test_set <- lapply(1:length(Test_set),function(i) {ets(Test_set[[i]], model = Forecast_Training_set[[i]])})`

Comment: I try this line of code but  some mistake occur.There is message " Error in Forecast_Training_set[[i]] : subscript out of bounds ".Please check if you can

Comment: Sorry for the first comment, I thought that the `window()` function returned a `list` object. Try with `Forecast_Test_set <- lapply(1:length(Forecast_Training_set),function(i) {ets(Test_set[,i], model = Forecast_Training_set[[i]])})`.